# Angular - Change BackGround Color of Row in Table After click the Buttom

Tags: css, angular, html-table, angular8

I want change the background color of the selected row after click the button
I tried but change the color of all rows.
This is a similar code.

> HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of (datas$ | async) | filter:authService.filter | paginate: config | orderBy: key : reverse" [ngClass]="{'data-selected':isSelected}">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.text}}</td>
    <td>
       <a class="mr-3" (click)="delete(data.id)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            Remove
       </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> TS

```
delete(postId) {
    this.isSelected=true;
    const ans = confirm('TEXT TEXT '+dataid);
    if (ans) {
      this.dataService.deleteData(postId).subscribe((data) => {
        if(data) {
          this.showSuccessDelete();
        } else {
          this.showError();
        }
        this.isSelected=false;
        this.loadDatas();
      });
    }
  }
```

> CSS

```
.data-selected{
  background-color: #e9eaea;
}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: The way you handle isSelected is not appropriate to my personal view. You could make this a part of the data structure and when you *ngFor your html you should apply it from the datastructure and when delete() is click you will receive the ID of the item and now change the state in the data structure... This way you can persist the current state when replaying it...

data :[ { name: "joe", selected: false}, ....]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an attribute to your component class and call it selectedRow, which will get the data.id.

```
selectedRow: number; 

delete(postId,numeroDeposito) {
this.selectedRow = postId; 
const ans = confirm('TEXT TEXT '+dataid);
if (ans) {
  this.dataService.deleteData(postId).subscribe((data) => {
    if(data) {
      this.showSuccessDelete();
    } else {
      this.showError();
    }
    this.isSelected=false;
    this.loadDatas();
  });
}
```

}

then in the tr tag use `[ngClass]="{'data-selected': selectedRow === data.id}"`.

Comment: Good solution, thanks so much, i dont know if chose your answer or the answer of @Adrita Sharma

Answer (score 3):

You can also take the following approach:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xd3yss)**

```
[class.data-selected]="data.isSelected"
```

and On click event.

```
(click)="data.isSelected = true";
```

Comment: Very good, i dont know if chose your answer or the answer of a bouchenafa

Comment: It is completely up to you. Don't forget to upvote though :D

Comment: I like you answer because it move the style logic from class body to template ,upvote for this

Comment: this solution could work for multiselection but from the context of the question, our friend here wants to select one row, to be shown as this row is getting deleted. Thank you for sharing your solution with us and for doing an example.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than declaring a separate `isSelected` variable. you should introduce is as a property of `data` object. Ex:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'AA',
    isSelected: false
}
```

Then on click you can toggle it when `delete` function is called with `data.id` as parameter.

```
deleteMe(id: string) {
    this.data.map(x => x.isSelected = false);
    this.data.find(x => x.id === id).isSelected = true;
}
```

And in html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data" [ngClass]="{selected: item.isSelected}">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="deleteMe(item.id)">delete me</button></td>
</tr>
```

Here is a minimum [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbzplb).

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional styling to achieve this.

`<div [className]="( checkSelectedRow(i) ? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>`

In Typescript file:

```
checkSelectedRow(rowNumber) : boolean {  
    for(int j=0; j<rows.length; j++){
       if(j==i){
         rows[i]["selected"]=true; return true;
       }; 
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be solve by create an array of selected rows like this

```
  deleteList = []
```

then when you click remove push the id of the item in the list

```
  delete(id) { 
    this.deleteList.push(id)
  }
```

then at the template use **ngClass** directive to set the class if the item id include in the list

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of list" [ngClass]="{'data-selected':deleteList.includes(data.id)}">
   ....
</tr>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mwne4)